# Determining audio level peaks with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Is there a plugin I'm missing that allows me to determine the volume samples over the length of an audio file?

For example, a sample of every second to gain the dB vs timestamp?

Comment: See [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/17702/1871), especially the ebur filter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ebur128` filter provides info in terms of the Loudness Recommendation [EBU R128](http://tech.ebu.ch/loudness) metric.

The `astats` filter can provide this info, in terms of dBs:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt -f null -
```

This produces an output like this:

```
frame:221  pts:226304  pts_time:4.71467
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-67.437152
frame:222  pts:227328  pts_time:4.736  
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-67.159036
frame:223  pts:228352  pts_time:4.75733
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-63.862748
frame:224  pts:229376  pts_time:4.77867
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-63.666815
```

If this is too fine-grained in terms of temporal resolution, increase the reset value which is the frame count for the filter's sampling frequency. For a 1-second slice, an integer approximating `audio sampling rate/1000` should be used.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this but if I change the reset value to samplingRate/1000, it returns the exact same output. I mean, if I use reset=44 (44100/1000), I have the exact same output. Any suggestion? I'm processing a flac file.

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Share the input if you can.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i mywav.wav -af astats=metadata=1:reset=44,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=gains.txt -f null -` this is my input. It doesn't matter if the input file is wav or flac or mp3 or wathever.

Comment: The input, not the command.

Comment: Do you mean the input file? If not, I don't know what are you talking about. One of the files I'm testing is this one: https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/flac/Symphony%20No.6%20(1st%20movement).flac

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get different readings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116653/discussion-between-jfvaldes-and-gyan).

Comment: Ok, you are right, I'm getting different readings but I get the same number of readings. What I'd like is to get just one reading per second, for example.

Comment: `-af asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt`

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue! I guess I'll have to set that asetnsamples with the same value as the audio sample rate, isn't it?

Comment: For 1-second readouts, yes.